# Connect two android applications to send and receive data

Tags: android, http, networking, cordova, data-sharing

I am developing a chatting app for android using phonegap , i have developed the UI but now im struck for how to connect two apps for sending and receiving data over internet, Messages in this case. I know this type of questions are not allowed on stackoverflow but im helpless.
Can anyone suggest what methodology or technology to use, i dont have a server all the data is stored locally in the mobile phone.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im not sure if its possible, maybe with node js.. anyway, you would probably need IP of both devices you would like to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Look at MQTT.

You can find references in http://www.eclipse.org/paho